# Access to Json get specific object result

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I'm want to get the JSON object uid and scores from the result for validation however when I trying to convert to string but the result always is null.

My Json:

```
[
   {
      "result":[
         {
            "uid":"1000",
            "scores":[94.00659834]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

my code:
The tempList is the place to stored JSON data.

```
List<FaceIdentifyModel> tempList = new List<FaceIdentifyModel>();
// insert data into tempList
tb_Identify.Text = tempList.ToJson();

foreach (var t in tempList)
{

       JObject jo_result = 
       (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(t.result.ToString());

       JArray jo_age = 
      (JArray)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jo_result["result"].ToString());

        id = long.Parse(((JObject)t)["uid"].ToString());  //get uid
        string scores = ((JObject)t)["scores"].ToString();//get scores
        int num1 = scores.IndexOf("\n") + 2;
        int num2 = scores.LastIndexOf("]")-8;
        ids = scores.Substring(num1, num2);
        scores_num =double.Parse(ids);
}
```

This is from API

```
    public static FaceIdentifyModel FaceIdentify(Image tempImage, string 
groupId, int userTopNum = 1, int faceTopNum = 1)
    {

        var client = new Face.Face(Config.clientId, Config.clientSecret);
        var image1 = ImageHelper.ImageToBytes(tempImage, 
System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        var result = client.User.Identify(image1, new[] { groupId }, 
userTopNum, faceTopNum);
        return result.ToObject<FaceIdentifyModel>();
    }
```

This is FaceIdentifyModel class

```
  {
    public List<FaceIdentifyUserInfo> result { get; set; }
  }
 public class FaceIdentifyUserInfo
 {
    public string uid { get; set; }
    public double[] scores { get; set; }
 }
```

jo_result "null object reference"

Comment: What is `tempList`?

Comment: A [mcve] would be really helpful here. I *strongly* suspect that you don't want the second `DeserializeObject` call, but it's hard to tell.

Comment: Like public List<FaceIdentifyUserInfo> result { get; set; } and I declare like  List<FaceIdentifyModel> tempList = new List<FaceIdentifyModel>();

Comment: "The tempList is the place to stored JSON data" - but what are the values in it? If you could provide a complete example so we don't need to be guessing at anything, that would be really useful. We don't need your actual types - feel free to simplify it, so long as it still reflects the problem you're trying to solve. So maybe you don't need the outer `foreach` loop at all - perhaps just hard code *one* string into the example.

Comment: Does `t.result` contain the content of the json you added to your question?

Comment: OK I think you need to take a step back from this and think about what you are doing. Why are you converting C# objects to JSON, and then converting that data back to C# objects in order to perform validation? Why aren't you performing your validation on the C# objects to start with?

Comment: @john The idea is like I send an image to cloud to do process then it will return the result to me as Json format. Therefore, I need convert to string to get the value.

Comment: But you're deserializing it to a C# object, so why don't you just use that? Could you show the definition of `FaceIdentifyModel` and then I can provide some C# code as an answer :)

Comment: @CodeNotFound t.result contain the json and allow me to check the value like user_info, scores.

Comment: @john sorry, edited the json.

Comment: Updated my example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the deserialized C# object:

```
List<FaceIdentifyModel> tempList = new List<FaceIdentifyModel>();
// insert data into tempList
tb_Identify.Text = tempList.ToJson();

foreach (var t in tempList)
{
    id = long.Parse(t.uid);
    scores_num = t.scores.First(); // or you might want to do average or sum
}
```